# Dragging custom UIView with shadow - the size resets and shadow disappears

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

In Xcode 5 I have created [an iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/DragTiles) with 5 "letter tiles", which can be dragged around:

[image: app screenshot]

The tiles are implemented as [Tile](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/Tile.h) class utilizing `Tile.xib` (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzevO.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

The `tile.png` is a small image without shadow:

[image: tile.png]

The `dragged.png` is a larger image with shadow:

[image: dragged.png]

The latter image is displayed by `touchesBegan` in [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/Tile.m):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    _background.image = kDragged;
    [_letter setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:48]];
    [_value setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];

    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    _background.image = kTile;
    [_letter setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]];
    [_value setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    _background.image = kTile;
    [_letter setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]];
    [_value setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];

    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

And dragging is done by using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/ViewController.m):

```
- (IBAction)dragTile:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    Tile* tile = (Tile*)recognizer.view;
    UIView* parent = tile.superview;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:parent];

        [tile setCenter:CGPointMake(tile.center.x + translation.x,
                                    tile.center.y + translation.y)];

        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:parent];
    }
}
```

**My problem is:**

When I touch a tile, its size increases and the shadow is displayed (which is okay).

But once I start dragging the tile, its size resets back to small with no shadow (which I don't understand).

I've set breakpoints at `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` - and the latter is being hit, when dragging starts. But why and how to stop this?

Comment: Why don't you do the view manipulation inside your gesture recognizer action? Check if `recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and set the big background + shadow, then reset it when `recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or cancelled... (don't know if the constant is correct)

Comment: I tried that already in my `dragTile:` method and then increasing the tile and displaying shadow happens too late: it happens when dragging starts and not (before) when user touches a tile. Here is my try in GitHub history: https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/0dff7843a81328f0af945fb496a83151da4e656e/DragTiles/DragTiles/ViewController.m

Comment: Ah I understand... then take a look at the option `cancelsTouchesInView` of the Gesture Recognizer (which is responsible for calling your `touchesCancelled` method) - if you disable this, then it should not get called anymore...

Comment: +1 that works, thanks! I wonder if I could/should get rid either of `touchesXXXXX` or `UIGestureRecognizer` - to stop mixing them...

Comment: Do you mind if I post that as an answer? - Well it sounds good to rely only on one solution, since the panning itself could easily be done in touchesMoved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the solution to the problem is to set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of `UIGestureRecognizer` to `NO` so that the `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` method is not called by the recognizer.

Refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView).